# capture multiple events in vue js, syntax?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

bear with me, you don't need to watch the video, nor read the github project, just for completeness:

from the [laracasts about vue js and form submit](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/19)

[see github project here](https://github.com/laracasts/Vue-Forms/blob/master/public/js/app.js)

```
 <form @submit.prevent="doSubmit()"  @keydown="form.errors.clear($event.target.name)">
```

this will clear the error of an element in case of "keydown" event. Now this won't work for `<select>` as users usually `click` or `change` for sure

so what I want to do is something like

```
<form @submit.prevent="doSubmit()"  @keydown@change="form.errors.clear($event.target.name)">
```

[but vue js does not seem to have syntax to do the same thing for multiple events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)

so only solution is:

```
 <form @submit.prevent="doSubmit()" @change="form.errors.clear($event.target.name)"  @keydown="form.errors.clear($event.target.name)">
```

I repeat the question:

**how to do the same thing for 2 different events?**

`@scroll@click` any 2 events

the actual solution to my problem is secondary

Comment: Your final example is fine. What's wrong with it?

Comment: well DRY: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself 
just imagine you have 5 events doing the same thing. To me its a smell. If I have to reread my code, I have to reread all event handlers to see if they are really exactly the same. Because if there is a small little difference there, good luck man. If it is the same, it should be called the same e.g. `@click@change=".."` that way you are sure at a glance it is the same, if it is not the same, it should be called like in the last example

Comment: this issue was discussed in https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6457. looks like there isn't a solution for this yet.

Comment: This does not violate DRY.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i cite: Violations of DRY are typically referred to as WET solutions, which is commonly taken to stand for either "write everything twice", "we enjoy typing" or "waste everyone's time"
yes, that is exactly WET

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
@keydown@change="form.errors.clear($event.target.name)"
```

use

```
@input="form.errors.clear($event.target.name)"
```

It will work for any input event occurs.

Comment: this does not answer the question. OP does not want "any" input events to trigger the method, he/she wants **two specific** events to cause a trigger.